# React Router Nested Routes not working, what should i do?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested

This is my react router three i have a problem when i call

http://localhost:5173/es/ redirect me to HomeComponent which is the desired behaviour, but when i try to call the nested routes like for example:
http://localhost:5173/es/products or http://localhost:5173/es/products/payfair is still redirecting me to HomeComponent what could be the error or why is not working properly the nested routes.

```
import { Suspense, useEffect } from "react";
import LoadingComponent from "./components/ui/Loader";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useNavigate,
  Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import HomeComponent from "./pages/home";
import ProductsComponent from "./pages/products";
import ProductPayFairComponent from "./pages/payfair";
import Providers from "./components/Providers";
import NotFound from "./pages/404";
import "./lib/i18n";

function UserRedirect() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    const defaultLanguage = "es";
    const redirectPath = `/${defaultLanguage}/`;
    navigate(redirectPath);
  }, [navigate]);

  return null;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingComponent isLoading={true} />}>
      <Providers>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/es/" />} />
            <Route path=""  element={<Navigate to="/es/" />} />

            {/* Routes in my page */}
            <Route path=":lang" element={<HomeComponent />}>
              {/* Nested route for "products" */}
              <Route path="products" element={<ProductsComponent/>}>
                {/* Nested route for "payfair" */}
                <Route path="payfair" element={<ProductPayFairComponent />} />
              </Route>
            </Route>

            <Route path="/:lang/error" element={<NotFound />} />
            <Route path="/*" element={<UserRedirect />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </Providers>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I try to call my nested routes like http://localhost:5173/es/products or http://localhost:5173/es/products/payfair but is still redirecting me to HomeComponent what could be the error or why is not working properly the nested routes.